# Trying to animate a hyperlink using CSS

Tags: css, hyperlink, css-animations

I'm trying to apply the animation `animation` to the hyperlink contained in the 3rd `<h4>` of a div `wpb_wrapper` of `.about_us_right`.

```css
.about_us_list_right .wpb_wrapper h4:nth-child(3) a  {
    -webkit-animation: animation 3s ease-out !important;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite !important; 
}
@-webkit-keyframes animation {
    0% { 
        color: red !important;
    }
    50% { 
        color: green !important;
    }
    100% { 
        color: red !important;
    }
}
```

Can anyone see what isn't working here? Am I not allowed to apply animations to hyperlinks?

I've applied these lines of code to different divs but never a hyperlink before!

Comment: Add your HTML too (for that part that contains the hyperlink), and yes, you should be able to add animations to hyperlinks

Comment: It works when I try it. I removed all the "Important" stuff though, jeez trust the code not everything needs "important."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bman70 said, you can not use important inside keyframes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

*Declarations in a keyframe qualified with !important are ignored.*

Comment: I have removed the !important declaration but that has not changed anything! Thank you I didn't know about the keyframe and !important declarations though! EDIT: Turns out a different color: white !important in a parent div was making the text white!

Comment: So you solved the problem? Couldn't understand... You will have to remove this !important from the parent if you want to animate

Comment: @KaiLPD haha those !importants will get you in trouble. But we couldn't see the whole code or someone would have noticed. Good example of why it's good to always post your full code. Of course we sometimes don't want to give away our secrets but it's harder to solve.

Answer (score 1):

So what isn't working about yours? Is it essentially the same as below?

I removed all the "!important" it was cluttering it up.
The anchor `<a>` tag IS actually inside the H4 correct? That's how I did it.

p.s. I assumed by "div wpb_wrapper of .about_us_right" you meant `.web_wrapper` is inside `about_us_right`.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes animation {
    0% {
      
        color: red;
    }
    50% {
      
        color: green;
    }
    100% {
      
        color: red;
    }
}

.about_us_list_right .wpb_wrapper h4:nth-child(3) a  {
    -webkit-animation: animation 3s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="about_us_list_right">

<div class = "wpb_wrapper">
<h4>First H4</h4>
<h4>Second H4</h4>
<h4><a href="the link">Third H4</a></h4>
</div>

</div>
```